# Manually Invoke Refresh on Custom AuthProviderPluginClass

Tags: namedcredentials, auth-provider, refresh-token, accesstoken

I have recently implemented a custom auth plugin provider in hopes of getting away from making a token call with every request OR having to manage the token myself.

I am using the Oauth 2.0 client credentials flow.

However, our API gateway is returning a 403 forbidden when the access token expires after one hour.

Unbeknownst to me, the refresh method of the custom auth provider plugin class is ONLY invoked when you receive a 401.

I am looking for a way to still utilize named credentials + auth provider + custom auth provider plugin to manage the tokens, but manually invoke the refresh method if I get a 403. I suppose I could generate a `Map<String,String>` and simulate the `config` by querying the metadata, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way that I am not able to find.

#### References to 401/403 difference:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CXzjQAG

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm

[Session Id not getting refreshed automatically with Custom Auth provider in Salesforce Named Credentials](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163224/session-id-not-getting-refreshed-automatically-with-custom-auth-provider-in-sale)

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: @Damecek, we were users of Apigee and ended up adding a policy at our mw/gateway to flip the status code.